# get header information from php curl post request

Tags: php, curl

I've been searching for hours and can't find anything on this. I'm doing a php curl post request to the sugarsync api and it returns a location in the headers that i need. i have no idea how to get this information. i have to keep it as a post because i post an xml file to their api and all they do is return header information. i have no clue how i can access the location in the headers. [according to them](https://www.sugarsync.com/developer?ref=/dev/getting-started.html) i need to put it into another xml file and post that as well. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

If you set the curl option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, cURL will follow the location redirect for you.

If you want to get the headers, set the option `CURLOPT_HEADER` to 1, and the HTTP response you get back from `curl_exec()` will contain the headers.  You can them parse them for the location.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // return HTTP headers with response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return the response rather than output it

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

list($headers, $response) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $resp, 2);
// $headers now has a string of the HTTP headers
// $response is the body of the HTTP response

$headers = explode("\n", $headers);
foreach($headers as $header) {
    if (stripos($header, 'Location:') !== false) {
        echo "The location header is: '$header'";
    }
}
```

See all of the options at [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/curl_setopt).

Answer (score 2):

To get the header information in the response.

```
curlsetopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
```

Comment: that gives me the header information. but how to i parse it to specifically get the location?