# Get Header from PHP cURL response

Tags: php, curl, header, response

I am new to PHP. I am trying to get the Header from the response after sending the php curl POST request. The client sends the request to the server and server sends back the response with Header. Here is how I sent my POST request.

```
   $client = curl_init($url);  
   curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
   curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   $response = curl_exec($client);
   var_dump($response);
```

Here is the Header response from server that I get from the browser

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 11:40:59 GMT 
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2Vycy9CYW9CaW5oMTEwMiIsIm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiMTIzNCJ9.kIGghbKQtMowjUZ6g62KirdfDUA_HtmW-wjqc3ROXjc Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server: Jetty(9.3.6.v20151106)
```

How can I extract the Authorization part from the Header ?. I need to store it in the cookies

Comment: Use e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Explode headers by newlines, explode each line by `:`, check which header is named `"Authorization"`, take its value.

Comment: This may be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11659510/297243

Comment: We are not allowed to re-post answers so please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925124/3897214

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It converts all headers into an array

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//enable headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//get only headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

$headers = [];
$output = rtrim($output);
$data = explode("\n",$output);
$headers['status'] = $data[0];
array_shift($data);

foreach($data as $part){

    //some headers will contain ":" character (Location for example), and the part after ":" will be lost, Thanks to @Emanuele
    $middle = explode(":",$part,2);

    //Supress warning message if $middle[1] does not exist, Thanks to @crayons
    if ( !isset($middle[1]) ) { $middle[1] = null; }

    $headers[trim($middle[0])] = trim($middle[1]);
}

// Print all headers as array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($headers);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Good answer, although you don't account for trailing newlines, or null values. You may get warnings: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`. I'm going to suggest an edit for review.

Comment: My edit was rejected as @user75ponic believes it is "superfluous". Sorry, but he's wrong. @Thamaraiselvam As my previous comment stated, your code does not account for trailing newlines which can, and often does, exist in header returns. The existence of a trailing newline causes this code to break entirely. Use `rtrim($output)` to fix that. You also don't handle null values at all and you will receive PHP warnings should any header contain a null value, again, a possibility. You can handle this like so:  `if ( !isset($middle[1]) ) { $middle[1] = null; }`.

Comment: @Crayons I will check and do the necessary changes +1

Comment: I suggest also to replace $middle=explode(":",$part); with $middle=explode(":",$part,2); because some headers will contain ":" character (Location for example), and the part after ":" will be lost.

Comment: @Crayons Thanks for your inputs and answer updated.

Comment: @Emanuele Thanks for your inputs and answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

For the first answer note that the code:

```
$middle=explode(":",$part);
```

will produce wrong results with string data containing `:`, like for example:

```
Sat, 14 Jan 2017 01:10:01 GMT
```

The correct code to split the fields to build the array would be like:

```
$middle=explode(":",$part,2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You just include this coding into your curl request

```
curl_setopt($curl_exec, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl_exec, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

after your curl execution use `$header_data= curl_getinfo($curl_exec);`

Then you get all the headers

```
print_r($header_data);
```

or use the [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
echo shell_exec("curl -I http://example.com ");
```

Comment: This gets the header of the request rather than the header of the response.

Comment: `curl_getinfo()` still doesn't return the response headers when you use the above code.  But setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURLOPT_NOBODY` *does* make `curl_exec()` return *only* the response headers.  Which is maybe useful if that's what you want, but the problem then is you only got the response headers and not the response body, and usually you want both.

Answer (score -4):

just use simple code to convert curl response to array.

```
 $response  = curl_exec($ch);
 $header_data= curl_getinfo($ch);
 print_r($header_data);
```

Comment: This gets the headers of the request rather than the headers of the response.