# get_headers add skip when external server not responding

Tags: php, get-headers

I use the following code to check the file size of a external pdf.
But I want to add a timeout and skip if the external server does not respond within 1 second. How can I achieve this?

My current code:

```
<?php
$newmanual = "https://www.example.com/file.pdf"
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($newmanual, TRUE)); 
$filesize = $head['content-length'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl has a timeout function, you could use that to get the headers.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/file.pdf");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//get only headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
// The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1); 
// The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); //timeout in seconds

$output = curl_exec($ch);
// close handle
curl_close($ch);

$headers = [];
$data = explode("\n",$output);
$headers['status'] = $data[0];
array_shift($data);

foreach($data as $part){
    $middle=explode(":",$part);
    $headers[trim($middle[0])] = trim($middle[1]);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dumo(headers);
```

Code taken from posts [how to set curl timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)
and [get header from php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978957/get-header-from-php-curl-response)